# Get 'owner' of class, if it is a property of another class

Tags: c#, class, properties

This is a more general question for better understanding on my part. Consider I have 3 Classes:

1. ClassA
2. ClassB
3. ClassC

Both ClassA and ClassB have ClassC as a Public Property like this:

```
class ClassA
{
    public ClassC cInstanceInA {get; set;}
}

class ClassB
{
    public ClassC cInstanceInB {get; set;}
}
```

Is there a neat way within my ClassC to determine if the current instance is the property of ClassA or ClassB?
This way I could do something like this

```
class ClassC
{
    public void myMethod()
    {
         if(IBelongToClassA)
         {
             //do something
         }
    }
}
```

I know, I could pass ClassA or ClassB (or there name/another identifier) as reference to the constructor of ClassC and store the information there, but I wanted to know if there is a more general way to do this.

Comment: It seems that ClassC should do something different. So what should it do differently then? This is an information that belongs to `ClassC` as property and `ClassA`/`ClassB` should provide that information.

Comment: I know what you mean by XY-problem, but this is not the case. No problem, no solution in my case, just a "Would this work and how?" The code in the question is just to make an example, but doesn't apply to any problem I actually would have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, unfortunately not. The instance itself can't *know* where it is, because in fact all objects are **stored in memory heap** and when you reference an instance, all you do is create a **managed pointer to that memory location**.

Even more - multiple objects can point to the same instance, so there can be **one-to-many** relationship, which shows that there can't be any built-in mechanism like this.

So if you want to create a parent-child relationship between the two classes and need to access the parent from `ClassC`, you will have to create some kind of reference within this class.

**Note:** Thanks to the garbage collector it is safe to have circular references, as those will get collected together when no longer referenced. This however is a **problem in Xamarin.iOS**, where you have to keep in mind that objects deriving from iOS-based classes will also be subject to reference counting in which scenario circular references will cause that the instances will stay in memory forever. To avoid this, you can decorate your properties with the `[Weak]` attribute, which Xamarin.iOS can recognize and break the strong circular reference. See [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/performance#weak-attribute) for more information.

Comment: Ok, that is what I thought. Would have been nice though.

Comment: I understand that it can be disadvantageous, but as a result you have higher flexibility - if you want to reuse an instance in multiple places, you can do so, if you don't, you can have the parent as a required constructor parameter.

Comment: He hasn't mentioned that he needs to access the parent. `ClassC` just wants to know from where it was instantiated to do something different then. It's a `bool`-condition, so this is probably a missing `bool` property in `ClassC` that needs to be assigned from the classes that initialize it.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I think OP last note states that he's trying to avoid it (same idea)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a nit way of doing it. But maybe add `myMethod` to both `A` and `B` classes? Something like :

```
class ClassA
{
    public ClassC cInstanceInA {get; set;}
    public void myMethod() {
      //Do something
      cInstanceInA.myMethod();
}

class ClassB
{
    public ClassC cInstanceInB {get; set;}
    public void myMethod() {
      //Do something
      cInstanceInB.myMethod();
}
```

Comment: Well that is a solution to the code posted, but that was just an example for the more general question